# В попытке заменить один элемент двухмерного массива, заменяются все элементы

Tags: python, массивы, циклы

очень странное, на мой взгляд, поведение массива. Предположим, у меня есть следующий код:

```
a = [[0, 1]] * 10
for i in range(5):
    a[i][0] = 3
print(a)
```

Любой здравомыслящий человек ожидает увидеть на выходе следующее:

[[3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]

Тем не менее, вывод оказался менее очевиден:

[[3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1]]

Помимо прочих, у меня есть одно желание - подставить действительное под струю ожидаемого. Тем, кто поможет, при встрече же пожму руку.

Comment: Кодом a=[[0,1]]*10 вы создаете 10 ссылок на один и тот же список [0,1]. Поэтому изменение хотя бы олной ссылки меняет их все. Это фича питона. S. Nick отаетил на ваш вопрос, правда, решил обойтись без объяснений.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[0, 1]] * 10

id(a[0]) # 98095944
id(a[1]) # 98095944
...
id(a[9]) # 98095944
```

---

```
a = [ [0, 1] for _ in range(10) ]
for i in range(5):
    a[i][0] = 3

print(a)

[[3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
```